# Copy last two columns and insert to the left of them

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble being able to copy the last two columns with data in a worksheet and then insert the same columns to the left of them. Here is my code so far, it copies the correct columns but it just pastes them to the right.

```
Sub GlobalPerformNewMonths()

Dim lngLastRow     As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Global Supplier Performance")
     lngLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(,Resize(lngLastRow,Copy .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, -2)
     Columns("D:AZ").ColumnWidth = 18.43
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting the entire columns of the data you want. Select them and then insert them to the left of the desired column.

```
Range("d:e").Select
Selection.Copy
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to shift from the last column found and [Range.Resize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176182%28v=office.11%29.aspx) to the appropropriate cells. To that end, I would suggest working with the [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) where numerically specific addressing is used.

```
Sub GlobalPerformNewMonths()
    Dim lr As Long, lc As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Global Supplier Performance")
         lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
         lc = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
         With .Cells(1, lc - 1).Resize(lr, 2)
            .Copy
            .Insert Shift:=xlToRight
         End With
         .Columns("D:AZ").ColumnWidth = 18.43
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```